# Trouble showing content with jQuery's .show()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a click handler on the "top level" `<li>`s that I want to hide all the content below the `<li>`s and then show the content below the particular `<li>` that was clicked.

The hiding works, but the showing does not.

```js
$('.menu li').click(function() {
  $('.submenu').hide();
  var myclass = $('submenu');
  $(this).show($submenu)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button>Menu</button>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Football</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">cricket</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Shane</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Waqar</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Waseem</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Akhtar</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Hockey</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Baseball</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Shane</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Waqar</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Waseem</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Akhtar</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: what should be your expected output?

Comment: Context on the problem is needed to give you a solution. Please example what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Explained what the code is trying to do, and what it does.  Also, made the code a testable snippet (using the [ <> ] box in the editing menu).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

It hides the submenu with CSS.
Then it toggles the submenu when you click the list item.

If you only want one submenu to be shown at once, uncomment the line in the js.

```js
$('.menu li').has('.submenu').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).find('.submenu').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.submenu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button>Menu</button>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Football</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">cricket</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Shane</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Waqar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Waseem</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Akhtar</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Hockey</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Baseball</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Shane</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Waqar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Waseem</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Akhtar</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
       <button>Menu</button>
       <ul class="menu">
         <li><a href="#">Football</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">cricket</a>
           <ul class="submenu">
             <li><a href="#">Shane</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Waqar</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Waseem</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Akhtar</a></li>
           </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">Hockey</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Baseball</a>
           <ul class="submenu">
             <li><a href="#">Shane</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Waqar</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Waseem</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Akhtar</a></li>
           </ul>
         </li>
         <div class="clear"></div>
       </ul>
     </div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
       $('.submenu').hide();
        $(document).on("click",".menu li",function(){  
             $(this).find('.submenu').slideToggle();
        });
     
     </script>
```

Comment: thanks you very much guys i got my problem solution with the help you guys

Comment: @Hafiz welcome. accept answer and do credits if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery and there is [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function for show/hide toggle and use like this

```
    $('.submenu').toggle();
```

and I fixed your script that doesn't work.

```
$('.menu li').click(function(){
  $('.submenu').hide();
  $(this).find('.submenu').show();
});
```

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d55m96kn/2/)**